# Reject JavaScript promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I am building an Angular application where I have a service for selecting items from a canvas. Once the user clicks a button that allows him to start selecting I also show a snackbar which informs the user that he is in *selecting mode* and he can start selecting. The snackbar has a cancel button that can stop the *selecting mode*. The problem is that the selection service returns a Promise that I have to reject if the user cancels the *selecting mode* from the snackbar. The code:

```
public startSelecting() {
  this.showSnackbar();
  
  // I wait for the user to select something
  this.selectionService.getSelection().then(selection => {
    // If the user selects an item I can close the snackbar
    this.snackbarService.close();

    // do something with the selection
  });
}

private showSnackbar() {
  this.snackbarService.show().subscribe(close => {
    // This is an observable that emits if the users cancels the snackbar,
    // therefore the selecting mode. Here I want to cancel the Promise from above
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The code isn't really clear at the moment. So the observable from `show()` emits `close` event? Why isn't function then called `close()`?

Comment: Yes, the observable from `show()`emits a `close` event, as the user is able to close the snackbar by clicking the _cancel_ button. There is a `close` function that I am calling if the user selects something (`this.snackbarService.close()`), I call this function to automatically close the snackbar after the selection is done.

Comment: I would not try to "cancel" the promise. Just ignore it. Make sure the `then` callback is a function that is also executed when the close-event arrives, so to avoid code repetition. Make sure that if that function is executed a second time, it is harmless.

Comment: Thanks @trincot but the function can't be executed a second time.

Comment: But surely you can make it so it exits when it executes a second time.